# What posts are within a radius of given longitude and latitudes?

Tags: wordpress

Given posts with a custom field

```
usp-custom-90
```

Which its value is a string

```
45.46135436613811,9.185124650000043
```

And having 2 values from a form GET

```
$lat = $_GET['usp-custom-20'];
$ln = $_GET['usp-custom-19'];
```

Which are 2 strings like:

```
45.461
9.177
```

How can I get all posts within `45.46135436613811,9.185124650000043`

I tried all sort of things but I am getting confused

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'meta_key'  => 'usp-custom-20',
            'meta_value'     => $ln,
            'compare'   => '>=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'usp-custom-19',
            'value'     => $lat,
            'compare'   => '<=',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Look into using the Haversine formula.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have but I don't understand it, I really have looked everywhere but I don't have those skills

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for example I have seen this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243687/post-queries-by-latitude-and-longitude but how would I apply it to my case?

Comment: The problem is the way you are phrasing your question.  It doesn't make any sense to ask what is within a given latitude/longitude value, because that is just a point.  Nothing is "within" that point, except for the point itself.  The usual question is to ask what is within a certain _radius_ of a given lat/long point.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75079/nested-meta-query-with-multiple-relation-keys

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok I have updated the quetsion title, the quetsion remains :(

Comment: @WasimSayyed that's in regards of dates tho

Comment: Still doesn't make sense, because you are asking for all posts within a _point_, not a radius of a point.  What is the radius?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I haven't defined a radius, I need to be able to define it, I was thinking of adding +$lat + 10 to auto generate a radius of +10 in respects of the lat or long

Comment: Ohh sorry the question is you are not getting correct decimal points

Answer (score 0):

```html
function search_nearby_locations( $latitude, $longitude, $min_distance = 0, $max_distance = 100, $limit = 10, $post_type = 'post', $use_miles = true ) {
        global $wpdb;
    
        $meta_key_latitude = 'usp-custom-20';
        $meta_key_longitude = 'usp-custom-19';
        $miles_to_km = $use_miles ? 1 : 1.609344;

        $prepared_query = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT p.ID, p.post_name, ((ACOS(SIN(%f * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) + COS(%f * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) * COS((%f - longitude.meta_value) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} latitude ON latitude.post_id = p.ID AND latitude.meta_key = %s
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} longitude ON longitude.post_id = p.ID AND longitude.meta_key = %s
        HAVING distance < %f",
        $latitude,
        $latitude,
        $longitude,
        $meta_key_latitude,
        $meta_key_longitude,
        $miles_to_km
        );

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($prepared_query);
        
        foreach ($results as $key ) 
          {
              $post_id[] = $key->ID;
          }
          
        return $post_id;
       
    }


    $result_posts = search_nearby_locations('45.46135436613811','9.185124650000043', $min_distance = 0, $max_distance = 100, $limit = 10, $post_type = 'courses', $use_miles = 30 );  // put latitude , $longitude , $radius as per your need in variable. 

// output - array(141,4587,1452,1547);

/*Put array post id in args query */

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $result_posts
    
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```